# Ошибка при чтении из файла

Tags: c++

Помогите разобраться с чтением из файла. Листинг указан ниже. Программа выполняется полностью, и только перед выполнением последней строки (`return 0`) выдает ошибку

> Необработанное исключение по адресу 0x77D2DF62 (msvcp120d.dll) в
>   test3.exe: 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при записи по адресу
>   0xFEEEFEEE.

В отладчике красным подсвечена переменная `argv` (аргумент функции `main` - указатель на массив аргументов командной строки). Если заменить `return 0` на `exit(0)` выходит без ошибок. В чем может быть проблема?

Листинг:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    std::vector<std::string> mystr{ "alfa", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "zetta", "hetha", "theta", "jotta" };

    std::ofstream fout;
    fout.open("E:/resources/test3.dat", std::ios::binary);

    size_t count = mystr.size();
    fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&count), sizeof(size_t));
    for (auto el = mystr.begin(); el != mystr.end(); el++)
    {
        fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(*el)), sizeof(std::string));
    }
    fout.close();

    std::vector<std::string> str1;

    std::ifstream fin;
    fin.open("E:/resources/test3.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (!fin)
    {
        std::cerr << "error!";
        exit(1);
    }
    size_t count1 = 0;
    std::string temp;
    fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&count1), sizeof(size_t));
    for (int i = 0; i < count1; ++i)
    {
        fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp), sizeof(std::string));
        str1.push_back(temp);
        temp = "";
    }
    fin.clear();
    fin.close();

    for (auto el : str1)
    {
        std::cout << el << '\n';
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема наверняка в `fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&count1), ...)`: вы читаете в `std::string` как в обычный буфер, а делать так категорически не стоит. `std::string` содержит указатель на буфер, который вы такой записью перезатираете и при попытке освободить память происходит ошибка.

Comment: Спасибо. Пробовал использовать  буфер char array, но проблема осталась ровно та же - необработанное исключение при исполнении return 0. Строки так же адекватно записываются и считываются, как и в предыдущем случае.

Comment: Обновляйте код. Пробуйте сначала только запись оставить, нужно найти минимальный код, который приводит к ошибке.

Comment: Запись идет нормально, без ошибок, к ошибке приводит часть чтения. Еще раз спасибо, буду пытаться разобраться.

Comment: Таки разобрался. Я не обнулял буфер перед записью и чтением. После обнуления все ОК. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну вообще проблемы с чтением-записью в необнуленный буфер быть не должно, если остальной код корректен.

Answer (score 0):

Программа не имеет смысла. В этом цикле

```
for (auto el = mystr.begin(); el != mystr.end(); el++)
{
    fout.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&(*el)), sizeof(std::string));
}
```

вы сохраняете в файле не строки вектора `mystr`, как вы очевидно предполагаете

```
std::vector<std::string> mystr{ "alfa", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon", "zetta", "hetha", "theta", "jotta" };
```

то есть не "alfa", "beta", "gamma" и т.д., а внутреннее представление объектов `std::string`, которые не содержат эти строки, а содержат некоторую служебную информацию (свойства класса) как, например, адрес на динамически выделенную память, где действительно хранятся строки, некоторый локальный буфер, используемый для оптимизации хранения коротких строк и .т.д.

Хранить эту информацию бессмысленно. Вам надо записать в файл именно сами строки, а не эту служебную информацию. Причем записывая строки, вы должны также сохранять информацию о длине строки, иначе вы не сможете их затем правильно прочитать. Например,

формат записи для каждой строки мог бы быть следующим:
длина строки, соответствующая значению, возвращаемому функцией класса `std:;string dize()`, а за ней сама строка символов.

Иначе у вас в этом цикле

```
for (auto el : str1)
{
    std::cout << el << '\n';
}
```

будет выводиться на консоль всякий мусор, а при завершении программы компилятор попытается вызвать деструктор строк, и в результате выскочит ошибка, на подобие той, текст которой вы привели.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но на консоль в указанном вами цикле выводятся те самые строки, считываются-то они правильно, а вот окончание программы аварийное.

Comment: @Игорь Гринев Программа имеет неопределенное поведение. Те же самые строки выводятся на консоль по той причине, что они короткие и хранятся в самом объекте std::string, а не в специально выделенной для них динамически памяти. Сделайте, например, строку длиной 40 символов и посмотрите, что будет выведено на консоль. Кроме того, вы не очистили предыдущий вектор, поэтому в цикле указатели могут ссылаться на элементы этого вектора. Очистите исходный вектор.